# pointer size not 8 bytes

Tags: c++

In my vs code in c++ when I declare a pointer and then print the size of the pointer, its reporting 4 bytes instead of 8 even though my system and compiler both are 64 bit.

Comment: This indicates that your compiler is in fact 32-bit, not 64-bit.

Comment: Or at least, is emitting 32-bit code. Whether the compiler binary is 64 bit or not is irrelevant. Chances are there's a project setting somewhere of x86 rather than x64, but you haven't told us anything about your project configuration.

Comment: *tried asking chat gpt but got no answer*...  This is a good reminder for you, ChatGPT will not be good enough to give you reliable (programming) answers.

Comment: Also using `vscode` as a beginner is not easy. What operating system do you use? Because on windows visual studio community edition is a much better beginner experience.

Comment: If you are on MS Windows and followed the steps in the official documentation you would have the latest MinGW and the pointers will be 64 bit: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Comment: `int main() {  int* pInt;  std::cout << "The sizeof(int*) is " << sizeof(pInt); }` printed "The sizeof(int*) is 8" for me compiled with the recommended g++ from msys2